# Rails Net::OpenTimeout Mailer Namecheap Heroku Unable to send mailer 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, timeout, actionmailer, namecheap

I attempted to send reset password email through a namecheap domain. I have reviewed every solution offered within StackOverflow and have not been able to get a viable solution. Let me know if I am missing any details below.
My Rails application is an API only.

It was working via gmail connection/smtp and when I switched it over to the namecheap/privateemail smtp it worked once.
After it worked locally I uploaded the code to heroku and that's when it started to fail.

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'noreply@domainemail.com'}

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '587'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

address:              'mail.privatemail.com',
port:                 587,
domain:               'domainname.com',
user_name:            ENV['EMAIL'],
password:             ENV['EMAIL_PW'],
authentication:       :plain,
enable_starttls_auto: true,
openssl_verify_mode:  'none',
ssl:                  true
}
```

Production:

```
config.cache_classes = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'noreply@domainname.com'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'mail.privatemail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'domainname.com',
  user_name:            ENV['EMAIL'],
  password:             ENV['EMAIL_PW'],
  authentication:       :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  openssl_verify_mode:  'none'
  }
```

NotifierMailer class

```
class NotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default_url_options[:host] = ENV['BACKEND_URL']
  default from: 'noreply@domainemail.com'


  def create
    admin = Admin.find_by(email: params[:email])
    admin.generate_password_reset_token!
    Notifier.password_reset(admin).deliver
  end

  def password_reset(admin)
    @admin = admin
    @url = "#{ENV['BACKEND_URL']}/password/reset?token=#{@admin.reset_password_token}&email=#{@admin.email}"
    mail(to: "#{@admin.first_name} #{@admin.last_name} <#{@admin.email}>",
         subject: "Ion Portal - Password Reset")
  end

end
```

Password controller

```
class PasswordController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  # include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: -> { request.format.json? }


  def forgot
    puts params
   if params[:email].blank? # check if email is present
    render json: {
       error: "Email not present"
     }
   end

   admin = Admin.find_by(email: params[:email]) # if present find admin by email
    if admin.present?
      admin.generate_password_token! #generate pass token
      NotifierMailer.password_reset(admin).deliver_now
      render json: { status: 'ok' }
    else
      render json: { error: ["Email address not found. Please check and try again."]}, status: :not_found
    end
  end

 def reset
   token = params[:token].to_s
   if params[:email].blank?
     return render json: {error: "Token not present"}
   end

   admin = Admin.find_by(reset_password_token: token)
   if admin.present? && admin.password_token_valid?
     if admin.reset_password!(params[:password])
       redirect_to "#{ENV['ION_URL']}"
     else
       render json: {error: admin.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
     end
   else
     render json: { error:  ["Link not valid or expired. Try generating a new link."]}, status: :not_found
   end
 end

 def update
   if !params[:password].present?
    render json: {error: 'Password not present'}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
   end

   if current_user.reset_password(params[:password])
     render json: {status: 'ok'}, status: :ok
   else
     render json: {errors: current_user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
 end

 def successful_reset
   render success_path
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 24 hours of trial and error I had to remove a couple of lines of code to make it work.

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
# For Gmail
      # :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      # :port                 => "587",
      # :domain               => "gmail.com",
      # :user_name            => "noreply@gmail.com",
      # :password             => "pasword!",
      # :authentication       => "plain",
      # :enable_starttls_auto => true

# For Namecheap

      :enable_starttls_auto => true,  #this is the important stuff!
      :address        => 'smtp.privateemail.com',
      :port           => 587,
      :domain         => 'privateemail.com',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => 'noreply@domainname.com',
      :password       => 'password!'
    }

I removed the following: 

    enable_starttls_auto: true,
      openss

    l_verify_mode:  'none'
```

Answer (score 1):

These settings worked for me.  Turned out I also had left the settings for MailCatcher as well, that was my initial problem.  Double check as well that what the domain setting and server address match, which in development, would mean setting the domain to 'localhost:3000'.  Good luck!

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => 'mail.privateemail.com',
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => 'localhost:3000',
:user_name            => 'email@email.com',
:password             => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
:authentication       => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
```